# create writing box in android studio

Tags: java, android

I would like to create a writing box in an app.The layout will be a sort of fill in the blanks kind of question interface. like the question is (man_o)*mango,beside the question there will be a box for the user to hand write the answer "g" ,and the letter"g"will be appear in the question,if wrong ,there will be a backspace button,but all of this cannot be involve a pop up keyboard ,any idea where to start guys?

Comment: you will have to extend an EditText with the required functionality. Or use just TextView + EditText + TextView. First TextView takes `man`, the second takes `o`, and the EditText expecting the `g` to be typed in.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting insight into this, it will help a lot.

https://github.com/vigneshwaranr/WikiGame